# AD Users sharing a Home Folder/Profile

Tags: active-directory, domain, login, users, roaming-profile

I'm facing a unique challenge.
As part of our transition to a new Active Directory Domain, we must ensure compliance by assigning each user a unique User Account identified by their name.surname

Given our frequent employee turnover, many users, particularly those in medical roles, will share common applications and files.

Is there a method to set up users to utilize a shared User Profile or Home Folder?

This would allow changes enforced on one user to automatically apply to others within the same group, such as software updates or printer additions.

Based on my research, it seems that Mandatory User Profiles or Roaming Profiles may not suit our needs for this scenario.

Modifying something on Profile1 would necessitate manual adjustments on Profile2, Profile3, and so forth, which isn't feasible for our requirements.

Is it feasible to link multiple sets of credentials to a single user account to avoid the hassle of managing profiles?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method to set up users to utilize a shared User Profile or Home Folder?

Not a reliable method. It can be problematic even for the same user, but multiple sessions in different hosts. There is the potential for conflict or overwrite.

> Is it feasible to link multiple sets of credentials to a single user account to avoid the hassle of managing profiles?

No, and this wouldn't solve anything.

Move the "shared" data to a folder external to the profile.

Answer (score 0):

> Given our frequent employee turnover, many users, particularly those
> in medical roles, will share common applications and files.

Welcome to every organization in the world. Create shared folders for users in similar roles who need access to the same data and secure accordingly. Use Group Policy to map the appropriate printers to the relevant users. Deploy your software via Group Policy (if possible). You can then apply updates to that software to all users using Group Policy.